# Looping a macro for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that runs through data looking for duplicate barcodes, then moves the 'oldest' duplicate (based off a date in another column) to another sheet.

Problem here is that I have multiple duplicates due to data entry error and need to run the macro at least 3 times. I would like this program to run automatically, so I need to loop this macro until there are no duplicates. I am thinking 'Do While' but would appreciate some guidance. Here is the code:

```
Sub DupMove() 'Moves the oldest duplicate to seperate sheet
Dim t As Single
Dim d As Object, x&, xcol As String
Dim lc&, lr&, k(), e As Range
xcol = "C"
lc = Cells.Find("*", after:=[a1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
lr = Cells.Find("*", after:=[a1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ReDim k(1 To lr, 1 To 1)
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each e In Cells(1, xcol).Resize(lr)
    If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then   
        d.Add e.Value, Array(Cells(e.Row, 5), e.Row)    
        k(e.Row, 1) = 1
    Else                            
        If d(e.Value)(0).Value < Cells(e.Row, 5).Value Then
            k(d(e.Value)(1), 1) = ""
            k(e.Row, 1) = 1
            d(e.Value)(0) = Cells(e.Row, 5)
            d(e.Value)(1) = e.Row
        End If
    End If
Next e
Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(lr) = k
Range("A1", Cells(lr, lc + 1)).Sort Cells(1, lc + 1), 1
x = Cells(1, lc + 1).End(4).Row
Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Copy Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A1")
Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Clear
Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(x).Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: If you sorted the data by barcode and then date you could just extract the first instance of each code.

Answer (score 1):

here's a crude way to find duplicates. adjust to your needs. You can place this in a worksheet change event (i dont recommend) but this does find all dupes

```
Private Sub this()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim this As String
    Dim arr(9)

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a10")

    For Each rCell In rng.Cells
        this = rCell.Value
        For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If this = arr(x) Then
                rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
                Exit For
            ElseIf this <> arr(x) And arr(x) = vbNullString Then
                arr(x) = this
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I can call on this macro to run as many times as I want, but I get an error returned when there are no more duplicates. How can I code in an "end sub" when no duplicates are found?

Comment: @AndyDufresne it might be specific to your code. This should run perfectly whether or not it finds duplicates. What error are you receiving?

Comment: I have mine remove the oldest duplicate to a new sheet and keep the newer instance. Due to data entry error I need the macro to run in a loop until there aren't any duplicates. The way it works now, when there are no duplicates remaining it returns a 400 error and stops the program.